# Use laptop as bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Does anyone know of a piece of software that will let me use my laptop (in this case OS X, but software for any OS would be interesting) as a bluetooth keyboard / mouse for use on another machine?

In this case I'm interested in using my laptop as a bluetooth keyboard on my PS3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Linux (and maybe you can compile it under OSX) there is hidclient. But i haven't tested it yet.
http://anselm.hoffmeister.be/computer/hidclient/index.html.en

Comment: Wow, that's pretty sweet actually. OP, you may have good results compiling this on OSX using GCC.

Comment: Does anyone knows same tool for windows (7 or 8)?