# Is there a way to turn my computer into a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth, ipad, tablet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use laptop as bluetooth keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/228881/use-laptop-as-bluetooth-keyboard)

Here are the facts:

- I have a computer (hurray!)
- It has a working bluetooth chipset
- It is running Linux (Debian)
- My tablet (an iPad, but it probably doesn't matter) supports bluetooth keyboards

Is there a way of turning my computer into an bluetooth keyboard ? That is, can I make my physical computer keyboard available to my tablet through bluetooth ?

Also, If you have a solution that involves Windows, I'm willing to take that too :)

Comment: Exact duplicate of question linked in the answer. iPad vs PS3 is only a minor difference that probably doesn't affect the question itself. (and if so it would be more about the specific table and thus off topic here on SU anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Use laptop as bluetooth keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/228881/use-laptop-as-bluetooth-keyboard)

Someone suggested using [hidclient](http://anselm.hoffmeister.be/computer/hidclient/index.html.en)

Comment: Next time better flag the question for being a duplicate.