# Expose a wired keyboard connected to a laptop to an iOS device as a Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a keyboard connected to my Windows laptop and I'd like to use it as a Bluetooth keyboard discoverable by my iOS device. In essence, I want my iOS device to be able to connect to the laptop via Bluetooth (which has a Bluetooth adapter) such that I can use my keyboard as input for my iOS device. How can I do this?

Comment: Reviewers, be advised that the (presently only) answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/228881/use-laptop-as-bluetooth-keyboard) won't be useful to the OP because it is for Linux and OS X, so voting to close as a duplicate of that question would not be a good idea. The question asks for a solution for Windows.

Comment: This requires Bluetooth hardware do you have Bluetooth hardware?

Comment: @Ramhound: That was indicated in the original revision of the question, but was left out when I rewrote it. Fixed.